# Next page button not displaying on right side of page css/html

Tags: html, css, web

```css
.pagination {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  &__previous {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: $color-grey-light-5;
    color: $color-black;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(.17, .67, .83, .67);
    &:hover {
      background-color: $color-grey-dark-4;
      transform: scale(1.1);
      color: $color-white;
    }
  }
  &__next {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: $color-dark-red;
    color: $color-primary;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(.17, .67, .83, .67);
    &:hover {
      background-color: $color-grey-dark-4;
      color: $color-black;
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination"> 
  <a href="#" class="pagination__previous"> &laquo;page 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="pagination__next">page 2 &raquo;</a>
</div>
```

*I am facing problem with move to next page button not displaying on right side of the page when I am on first page however when I am on second page it works fine. Any help is appreciated.*

Comment: This is the HTML part of the code:                                                                                                                  
     <div class="pagination">
                
                   <a href="#" class="pagination__previous"> &laquo;page 1</a>
                  <a href="#" class="pagination__next">page 2 &raquo;</a>
                       
     </div>

Comment: Try to remove (margin-left: 1rem;) from &__previous part

Comment: I edited your snippet with the HTML code you provided in the comments. From within the snippet it looks fine for me. the next page Button is displayed at the right as intended. Maybe clear your browser cache.

Comment: I have cleared browser cache but button still appears on the left side-@tacoshy

Comment: On the first page the previous button is not on the page (or on the last page the next button isn’t there). - @tacoshy